# I have been trying to enable the Node.js support on PhpStorm but it freezes at the dialog box, how can I fix this?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, phpstorm

I am trying to get code support on my PhpStorm v10.0 for my Vue files. I have both Node and Vue plugins downloaded. I have also downloaded Node(v10.16.3) on my laptop.

The problem: It freezes at the dialog box that's seen from the screenshot (of PhpStorm). Is there an alternative way or a way to fix this problem?

[image: PhpStorm Screenshot]

[image: Vue]

[image: Node]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately PhpStorm 10 doesn't support recent Node.js versions. **Node.js Core** library can't be enabled when using Node.js *6.x - 12.x*, debugging won't work, etc. You have to either downgrade Node.js to v.*4.x* or upgrade PhpStorm to the most recent version (2019.2.x)

Comment: I checked up and I do have the latest version of PhpStorm i.e. PhpStorm v10.0

Comment: the latest PhpStorm is 2019.2.3 - see https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download. PhpStorm v10.0 was released 4 years (and 11 major versions) ago, so it's definitely not the latest one